# showing the div with waste vertical space when I click on the link

Tags: jquery, html, css

here is my **structure**:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                       |
|                      header {position: fixed;}                        |
|_______________________________________________________________________|
|                                                                       |
|                     title1  |   title2  | title3                      |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|   tile1: here is a explanation ...                                    |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|   title2: here is a explanation ...                                   |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|   title3: here is a explanation ...                                   |
|                                                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

here is my **codes**:

```
<div id = "header">header</div>    

<a href="#title1">title1</a>
<a href="#title2">title2</a>
<a href="#title3">title3</a>

<div id="title1">tile1: here is a explanation ...</div>
<div id="title2">tile2: here is a explanation ...</div>
<div id="title3">tile3: here is a explanation ...</div>
```

Now when I click on the `title1` *(link)*, the related div is displayed in the top of page, under the header *(because header is fix)*.

here is my **output**: *(when I click on the title1)*

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                       |
|                      header {position: fixed;}                        |
|_______________________________________________________________________|
|   title2: here is a explanation ...                                   |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|   title3: here is a explanation ...                                   |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

While I want this output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                       |
|                      header {position: fixed;}                        |
|_______________________________________________________________________|
|   title1: here is a explanation ...                                   |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|   title2: here is a explanation ...                                   |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|   title3: here is a explanation ...                                   |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
|                                                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

how can I do that ?

---

**Edit:**

here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5akh7va2/4/) .

Comment: You're going to have to use Javascript because the fixed header is hiding title1. Either that or pad the titles with CSS, possibly.

Comment: @taco how ? *(This is something that matters)*

Comment: where is your header html? post that too

Comment: post ur complete html plus javascript whatever you have done so far

Comment: @Alex header is the first. check out my update

Comment: this is not complete by matching it to what u said in post

Comment: why dont you create a fiddle, it would be easier to help

Comment: @Alex my full code is too much, do you know what I want ? so if you can help me ... my codes that I have done does not works, why should I attach them ..!

Comment: @TheUknown ok, I will create ...

Comment: check out my demo. I think it should work for you.

Comment: @TheUknown check out my fiddle ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your content with a `div` and make fixed position as well without resorting to JS:

HTML:

```
<div id="header">header</div>    
<div id="content">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#title1">title1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#title2">title2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#title3">title3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="title1">tile1: here is a explanation ...</div>
    <div id="title2">tile2: here is a explanation ...</div>
    <div id="title3">tile3: here is a explanation ...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    background-color: lightGrey;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    background-color: Grey;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;    
}
```

For illustration see this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tmvmazdg/3/

Comment: you used of `200px` padding for each `div`. please check your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tmvmazdg/2/). I used of `<br>` instead `padding`. can you solve it now ?

Comment: @stack I see what you mean, it doesn't indeed work. Without resorting to JS I would suggest you implement your content as a fixed div as well and manually enable y scroll by setting overflow-y: scroll; http://jsfiddle.net/tmvmazdg/3/

Comment: your Idea is great ...! thanks. just one question, your idea (fixed content and overflow-y scroll) works on every browser ? even old one ? (IE 7)

Comment: @stack IE7 should work. Just make sure your page has a valid doctype to trigger standards mode. Usually `<!DOCTYPE html>` will be enough for all browsers. IE6 does *not* support `position: fixed;`.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to handle this via Javascript.

Here is a demo how to do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/h2020bpn/3/

Here is an example using jQuery, so it will work cross browser. You could easily re-use this code to fit your purpose.

This uses jQuery's [.scrollTop() method](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/):

`Set the current vertical position of the scroll bar for each of the set of matched elements.`

Comment: My problem is not solved. check out your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h2020bpn/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can and probably should do this with styling.

You want to add a padding to the top of your body element, equal to the height of your banner. Then you need to set your banner's coordinates, so they're relative to the HTML element instead of the body element.

This should be in a stylesheet, but just editing what you have there (assuming your banner is 50px):

```
<body style="padding-top: 50px;">
    <div id="header" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px;>header</div>
...
</body>
```